# How to use ngx-scanner module angular desktop app?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, qr-code

I am using ngx-scanner module in my responsive app.Currently I am using this app on my laptop and it is opening front camera and I am getting scan completed event and scan error only?
I am not sure if i am using this module properly or not.
Is there any way that we can use module in desktop application?

Comment: How are you generating your *Desktop application* ?

Comment: I just imported ngx-scanner module and this is my code:

Comment: <button (click)="scanStart()">Scan QR CODE</button>
  <zxing-scanner [enable]="scannerEnabled"
    [(device)]="desiredDevice" 
    (camerasFound)="camerasFoundHandler($event)"
   (scanSuccess)="scanSuccessHandler(event)"
    (scanError)="scanErrorHandler(event)"
    [enable]="scannerEnabled"
    (scanError)="scanErrorHandler($event)"
    (scanComplete)="scanCompleteHandler(event)"></zxing-scanner>